# What should be input and output for CA3020A power amp circuit and how to implement it?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, power-electronics, power-amplifier

I am trying to rig up Figure 1b and Figure 8 circuit from datasheet  to test the power amplifier CA3020A.
Not able to understand the datasheet my doubts are

1. figure 1b what are values of vcc1, vcc2 ,ein and how to check output w.r.t input. What is meaning of class b power amplifier
2. figure 8 what should I determine in this and how do I verify the input and output.

My main objective is to check CA3020A component and if any other method is there kindly suggest I am a beginner so kindly explain

[image: Figure 8]

[image: Figure 1]

[CA3020A](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/176938/INTERSIL/CA3020A.html)

Comment: It's a really old and obsolete product so why the interest in this dinosaur?

Comment: @Andy aka Haha having few of these components so thought why to waste it rather make something of it but first need to test if its working any ideas?

Comment: Would you bother baking a cake with 40 year old flour?

Comment: Google class b power amplifier. No need to ask here. I’m with Andy. You’re making a rod for your own back.

Answer (score 0):

An archaeological dig through data books came up with RCA Victor Co.; *RCA linear integrated circuits* 1967.
Single-supply range is from +3 to +9V DC.

*Absolute maximum voltage* for the differential amplifier (I take it this is pin 11) is +12V DC.
*Absolute maximum voltage* for output stage, peak-to-peak is 20V
*maximum input voltage* (single-ended) is +/- 3V p-p

About "class-B" output. This amplifier is really crude - when they say "class-B", they mean that there is **no provision** whatsoever to reduce cross-over distortion. Both circuits 1(b) and fig 8 have this problem. You should re-consider using this chip in audio applications for this reason.

Figure 1(b) circuit is similar to one in this reference book, with the exception of the 1k DC bias resistor attached to pin(11), which is missing (infinite resistance) in the reference circuit. What is maddening, is that audio transformer turns ratio is not given. However, the reference circuit does give Vcc1, Vcc2: both **+9V DC:**

- 3.3% distortion (@ 135mW power out)
- Idling current is given as 22mA.
- Input resistance is given as 50k ohms
- Input voltage for full-power output: 44mV
- Maximum audio output power: 545mW

For figure 8, a reference circuit with 65 ohm load resistors is given, instead of 50 ohms in OP's circuit. This gives slightly more gain \${e_{out}} \over {e_{in}} \$ of 44 dB.

Once again - this ancient circuit is flawed; suitable only for nostalgic reasons -  otherwise, use something more modern.

Comment: Thank you that was really informative. Do you have any other method in your mind or would prefer  to test these in a simple manner?

Comment: Those output transistors (pins 4,5,6,7) provide no useful output unless they're wired somewhere (by you). Fig 8 circuit is about the simplest test circuit providing any useful output with Vcc1=Vcc2.